# Webview does not render PayPal page

Tags: webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have been struggling with this issue for the past 2 days but paypal login page which used to render on a webview does not render any more and I get a blank page. I see the spinning wheel for a second and see that the page is rendering but then suddenly everything goes blank. This is a new issue and the page used to work correctly.
When I look at Safari Debugger and see that a whole bunch of .js files fail to load.
The same redirect URL which PayPal returns does render in a browser.

Here is the appcelerator code:

```
var webView = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url: encodeURI(Alloy.Globals.paypalURL + _URLParams), // URL to PayPal
    top: 0,
});
webView.ignoreSslError = true;
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    top:Alloy.Globals.TitleBarHeight,
    left:0,
    bottom:0,
    right:0
});
view.add(webView);

$._helpWindow.add(view);
```

On the server side I have the following:

```
paypal.payment.execute(pPaymentID, details, function (error, payment) {       
    if (error) {
        console.log("ERROR: UserModel::makePayPalPayment::paypal.payment.execute: ", error);
        return pCallback(error, null);
    } 
    else {
        . // more code here
        .
        .
    }
```

There are no errors on the server side. And when I take the return URL from PayPal and look at it using a browser, it renders correctly.

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6S4417991G737070N
```

Hard coding the above URL to this line of code also shows a blank page.

```
url: encodeURI(Alloy.Globals.paypalURL + _URLParams),
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the url you are using for PayPal and some source code of how you are doing it..is it happening only in iOS or in Android as well...?

You might need to check for some security reasons in WebView.

Comment: Provide a code example with the URL you are trying to load. It could be that there's an error on the page which you are loading...

Comment: Please see my comments

Comment: Ok I figured it out: After removing bencoding.blur and dk.napp.ui, PayPal renders again in a WebView. So bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

For any one who may have this issue in the future: I removed bencoding.blur and dk.napp.ui modules from my project and now PayPal renders correctly in a WebView.